# Reference request — fishery yield optimization

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, reference-request, industry

I'm looking for references to do a review of research on managing fisheries in industry. I've seen adaptions of
population growth models which include some harvesting constant or function and was wondering what has been done in the area, particularly with respect to variable prices and how temperature or nutrients could affect the yield of the fish.